# How to fix "No resource identifier found for attribute ‘style’ in package ‘android’"?

Tags: android

I created a style and applied it to a button, but when I try to build I get the exception:

`No resource identifier found for attribute ‘style’ in package ‘android’`

This is the button's code:

```
<Button
            android:text="Settings"
            android:style="@style/SecondaryButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the style tag does not need the android package namespace, even though many IDEs will suggest that as correct. So instead of:

`android:style="@style/SecondaryButton"`

use:

`style="@style/SecondaryButton"`